# Raw SHA1 in java does not match the one in PHP

Tags: java, php, sha

I have checked for similar questions in SO but none of those could answer my question so posting my question here. 
I need to generate raw SHA for a password before making third party API call in my code. 
I am using DigestUtils present in apache codec library. Following is the java code

```
public static String sha1 (String input) 
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
        UnsupportedEncodingException {

    return new String(DigestUtils.sha(input));
}
// I suppose this gives me raw SHA.
```

And the PHP code (i got in google) is below

```
$passwordSha = sha1($password, true);

// The boolean value gives the SHA in binary format.
```

For input "PASSWORD" , following are the outputs

```
JAVA : "+��0G���i.)�\�I�_�7"
PHP  : "+��0G���i.)�\�I�_�7"
```

I am not sure if am right in comparing these junk values however, my final password digest that i generate, which is dependent on above code is different in PHP and JAVA. (Getting right value in PHP).

Please help me know the difference in generating raw SHA1 in PHP and JAVA.

**UPDATE**

Edited the outputs. My bad..

Some more results for different inputs

input : "secretnonce101112015-09-30T14:12:15Z��a�����`�t�.�^X�"

JAVA : "�s�� ���A�M��;���*"

PHP  : "���i>�рq��������"

I see some extra characters in java output. Not sure if this is ruining my final password digest.

Comment: Converting random bytes to a `String` is pretty useless. A hex string is a lot more readable. But what's your point, you're getting the same values from both systems so...?

Comment: There was some issue in pasting the output. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using ISO-8859-1 encoding while converting to String, i got the correct output.

So the String should be converted to byte[] with ISO-8859-1 encoding

byte[] passwordSha = sha(input.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));

This worked for me.. 
Referred [PHP and Java hmac hash output matches in hex, doesn't match in raw binary. What's happening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824108/php-and-java-hmac-hash-output-matches-in-hex-doesnt-match-in-raw-binary-what) for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're losing stuff in the type-casting to a String somehow, but can you please try the following and compare the outputs? This should represent both as a hex string.

```
public static String sha1 (String input) 
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
        UnsupportedEncodingException {

    return DigestUtils.sha1Hex(input);
}
```

vs

```
$passwordSha = sha1($password, false);
```

Comment: Yes. I get same output for shaHex() and sha1($password, false). Basically hex representation is giving same output in java and php. I am not sure while using raw SHA1 what is going wrong. And yeah, the third party API expects us to generate raw SHA, thats how struck in this

Comment: Then it has to be the type casting, what about:

return new String(DigestUtils.sha1(input), "US-ASCII");

Comment: JAVA :�s�� ���A�M����;���*

PHP : ���i>�рq��������

Still not same. I am clueless on what can be going wrong

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this, but if the Hex values are the same you could always add a Hex Decode to it:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html

Comment: @pavitrashanbhag Are you running both through your API to compare, or are you printing to the screen to compare? Maybe they are the same but the difference is in how non-printable characters are printed.

Comment: The API documentation has certain inputs and expected password digest. Since we are implementing in java, am writing java code which is not generating expected output digest. Their doc contains PHP code used to generate digest. So am running PHP code online and comparing on screen with java. 
Yeah may be this is non printable but certainly the base64 encoded output of PHP code and java doesnt match. So am doubting this SHA algorithm.

Comment: String finalDigest = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(digestSHA.getBytes()));

PHP code : 

$passSHA = base64_encode($finalSha);


Can these produce different outputs?

Comment: Can you replace your examples with the base64 outputs you're receiving from both Java and PHP? That will be more clear to look at than the non-printable stuff that is probably getting mangled even more on stack overflow.

Comment: Inputs as follows

password = "PASSWORD", nonce = "secretnonce10111", timestamp="2015-09-30T14:12:15Z"

final output formula = base_64(sha(nonce + timestamp + sha(password)))


JAVA OUTPUT : T5/wDW189oUilVTZDPZsv106DvI=

PHP OUTPUT : u4mCPOVhlyM2vL4422fzeXeLCeY=

Comment: Hey, I got the correct answer. I was supposed to use ISO-8859-1 charset encoding while converting to string. I got this idea after seeing your comment on US-ASCII and then got one link in SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824108/php-and-java-hmac-hash-output-matches-in-hex-doesnt-match-in-raw-binary-what.. This helped. Thanks a lot for your help :) Closing the thread